# Using TET to get Font List from PDF returns length:fonts = 0

Tags: pdflib

This always returns 0 even though the PDF has several embedded fonts.

Im using TET4.1 PHP 5.3 Linux

$fontCount = (integer) $tet->pcos_get_number($doc, "length:fonts");

All other calls using $tet->pcos_get_number($doc, "xxxx") work fine.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing details I can only guess:

- the document contain the fonts only within form fields
- no fonts are used and the visual text comes from raster images

I guess in this case, it might be good recommendation to contact the vendor directly. 
http://www.pdflib.com/licensing-support/opening-a-support-case/